# Dual bundle transition functions

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

We can show that the dual bundle $E^*$ with fibers $(E^*)_x = (E_x)^*$ for all $x \in B$ have transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta} = (f_{\alpha\beta}^T)^{-1} : U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \to GL(r,\mathbb R)$.

However, I can't seem to show that the $g_{\alpha\beta}$ satisfy the cocycle conditions, that is $g_{\alpha\alpha} = \text{Id}_F$ for $x \in U_\alpha$, $g_{\alpha\beta} \circ g_{\beta\alpha} = \text{Id}_F$ for $x \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ and $g_{\alpha\beta} \circ g_{\beta\gamma} \circ g_{\gamma\alpha} = \text{Id}_F$ for $x \in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \cap U_\gamma$.

How might we compute that the cocycle conditions are satisfied?

Comment: Now that you've added the transpose, don't the cocycle conditions fall out easily? If not, edit your question to show exactly where you get stuck.

Comment: @TedShifrin ah yes, that's been added

Comment: ah, completely my bad it was much easier than i thought :)

Comment: Why don’t you write your own official answer now?